# Why doesn't this work (javascript + audio player)

Tags: php, javascript, audio-player

I am trying to use the JavaScript audio player(http://wpaudioplayer.com/standalone/) on my website. I tried passing PHP variables into the JavaScript but it does not seem to work properly. The JavaScript replaces the html paragraph with a matching id into a flash mp3 player.

EDIT: Updated the issue

If I pass the url directly, the mp3 player plays but when I pass it through a variable it does not.

This works

```
<p id="audioplayer_<?php echo $i ?>">Install flash to use mp3 player</p>
            <script type="text/javascript">  
            var id = "audioplayer_" + <?php echo $i ?>;             
        AudioPlayer.embed(id, {soundFile: "http://site.com/mp3file.mp3"});  
        </script>
```

But this does not

```
 <p id="audioplayer_<?php echo $i ?>">Install flash to use mp3 player</p>
                <script type="text/javascript">  
                var id = "audioplayer_" + <?php echo $i ?>; 
                var url = "<?php echo $url ?>";             
            AudioPlayer.embed(id, {soundFile: url});  
            </script>
```

The value of the $url variable is http://site.com/mp3file.mp3

Comment: Can you show the generated HTML code, please?

Comment: Alright. I included the output

Comment: Now you excluded the generated HTML again. Please include both versions' HTML.

Comment: Also, if you need an example web address, don't use existing web addresses like [site.com](http://site.com), rather use [example.com](http://example.com) or example.org.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put quotes around the url, because to JavaScript it is a string. Change your PHP code to

```
<p id="audioplayer_<?php echo $i ?>">Install flash to use mp3 player</p>
        <script type="text/javascript">  
        var i = <?php echo $i ?>;
        var url = "<?php echo $url ?>";
    AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_" + i, {soundFile: url});  
    </script>
```

Comment: Cool. Now the player is embedded but theres a new problem. I updated the original post

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need the variables at any other place, don't use them and try this

```
<p id="audioplayer_<?php echo $i ?>">Install flash to use mp3 player</p>
<script type="text/javascript">  
AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_<?php echo $i; ?>", {soundFile: "<?php echo $url; ?>"});  
</script>
```

with this code you avoid "variable issues"